# Simplifying this Tkinter For Loop to Update Entry Values between two columns

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

This script works fine for doing what I want it to, but I think there's likely a far more direct alternative that I'm missing.

All I have is a tkinter checkbox that when pressed, runs this function that maps all the info from column 0's rows of entry boxes into column 1's entry boxes. Currently, this is the script:

```
def update_company_new():

    company = str()

    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        if child.grid_info()["column"] == 0:
            company = child.get()
        if child.grid_info()["column"] == 1:
            child.insert(0, company)
```

Is there a more direct way to do this? This seems something that could normally be done with a simple list comprehension but I can't find enough details on additional options for `winfo_children()` and `grid_info()` that make it adaptable to tkinter `grid` references.

Comment: this is fine depending on what order the widgets are added to the `frame`, possibly you would want to have lists for each column and then iterate over the lists instead, then the order wouldn't matter, or use an additional frame for each row, that way the entries are grouped in one frame, but otherwise this seems ok

Comment: Unclear what you're thinking or hoping to find because list comprehensions are for creating lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using list comprehension:

```py
[frame.grid_slaves(row=w.grid_info()['row'], column=1)[0].insert(0, w.get()) for w in frame.grid_slaves(column=0)]
```

But it is hard to understand for beginner and it created an useless list of `None`.

It is better to use a simple for loop instead:

```py
for w in frame.grid_slaves(column=0):
    row = w.grid_info['row']
    peer = frame.grid_slaves(row=row, column=1)
    # check if there is Entry in column 1
    if peer:
        peer[0].insert(0, w.get())
```